# BA's full security name is "BOEING CO COM USD5.00". What does "COM USD5.00" mean?

Tags: stocks

1. Is this the par or nominal value?
2. If so, how can it be represented as 5 USD? Undeniably BA's share price has outstripped 5 USD.

Comment: Par value has no connection to market value.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is Common Stock, Par Value.

See other questions regarding the purpose of Par Value:
[Relation between par value, offering price and trading range](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109166/relation-between-par-value-offering-price-and-trading-range?rq=1)

Inspect the 10-K filing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

"COM" means "common stock".

"USD5.00" is the par value of each share.

> Is this the par or nominal value?

Par value.

> If so, how can it be represented as 5 USD? Undeniably BA's share price has outstripped 5 USD.

Par value is not market value. Par value is usually only relevant when the company is issuing shares; the newly issued shares cannot be sold for less than the par value.