# What is period end basic number of $0.50 ordinary shares outstanding?

Tags: stock-markets, accounting, stock-exchanges, shares, balance-sheet

I was checking HSBC 2020 Q1 earnings release's balance sheet, and under share count, the first line says "period end basic number of $0.50 ordinary shares outstanding." I believe that the first line simply means the number of shares outstanding in the market. But, would anyone know what's the need to say "period end basic number of $0.50"?

I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relation between par value, offering price and trading range](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109166/relation-between-par-value-offering-price-and-trading-range)

Comment: @base64 appreciate the comment, but I'm not sure if that question relates 

Comment: Without seeing any more detail, I would assume it just means the number of shares outstanding at the end of the period in question... that is, at the end of Q1 2020, whenever that was.

Comment: @BøbbyLeung The $0.50 is the par value (per share) of the 20.172 billion shares outstanding at the end of the accounting period.